# C programming using touch command

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that changes the access and modified time stamp of a file given by the user. This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char file[50];
    printf("Enter file to be modified: ");
    scanf("%s", &file);
    system("touch -am -t 200005050000 %s", file);
    return 0;
}
```

The program does not change the file time stamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `system` function doesn't support stdio-style formatting codes such as `%s`. You need to pre-create the command string using a call that does understand them, such as `snprintf`, and pass the result to `system`. For example:

```
char command[256];
snprintf(command, sizeof command, "touch -am -t 200005050000 %s", file);
system(command);
```

Note that this approach (as well as your original attempt) will fail to work for files whose names contain whitespace or quoting characters. To operate on such files, you should either surround the file name with quotes, or switch to less portable low-level process creation APIs, such as `execlp` on Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
scanf("%s", &file);
```

When scanning for strings, you don't use `&`.
Instead, it should be:

```
scanf("%s", file);
```

Comment: That line is wrong, but it is not the cause of OP's problems. Taking the address of an array will evaluate to a pointer pointing to the same address as the first array element, so the `scanf` call will work, despite being technically incorrect.

Comment: It's not wrong, the `&` operator is redundant. That's different. A C array is already a pointer so the `&` is not required, but it still works.